# Spring jpa specifications OR clause returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications

i'm trying to implement this in my project:

```
        Specification<Delivery> shipmentSpec = ((root, query, builder) ->
                builder.or(builder.equal(root.join("entries").get("shipment").get("senderGeography"), geo),
                           builder.equal(root.join("entries").get("shipment").get("receiverGeography"), geo)));

        Specification<Delivery> collectSpec = ((root, query, builder) ->
               builder.equal(root.join("entries").get("collect").get("geography"), geo));

        repository.findAll(Specification.where(shipmentSpec).or(collectSpec);
```

And it doesn't return anything. but it works good if i use only one spec like: `repository.findAll(Specification.where(shipmentSpec));`

or

`repository.findAll(Specification.where(collectSpec));`

Delivery entity has field :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "delivery")
private List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

And Entry entity has fields:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SHIPMENT_ID")
private Shipment shipment;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "COLLECT_ID")
private Collect collect;
```

One of those fields always null, but not both at the same time.

Shipment and Collect entities has fields:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "GEOGRAPHY_ID", nullable = false)
private Geography geography;
```

(Shipment has 2 geographies)

I need an option to return all Delivery entities which has in it's entries shipment OR collect with specified geography.

Thanks.

**UPDATED.**

I have tried to get entities with @Query but it's acts the same as specification method, returns empty list:

```
@Query("select d from Delivery d, Entry e where e.delivery.id = d.id " +
        "and (e.shipment.senderGeography = ?1 or e.shipment.receiverGeography = ?1 or e.collect.geography = ?1)")
List<Delivery> findByGeography(Geography geo);
```

It's working only if i left `(e.shipment.senderGeography = ?1 or e.shipment.receiverGeography = ?1)` or `e.collect.geography = ?1` clause in a query. 
But not both.

Comment: If you'll never have both values as null, and you need all rows with one of the values specified, then why can't you select all rows?

Comment: Can you clarify that `repository.findAll(Specification.where(shipmentSpec).or(Specification.where(collectSpec)))` doesn't or does work for you? Also, can you show what are inside `shipmentSpec` and `collectSpec` at the time of request?

Comment: @ayrton How can i do that with specifications? The problem that it doesn't return anything if i wrote like : builder.or(builder.equal(root.join("entries").get("shipment").get("senderGeography"), geo), builder.equal(root.join("entries").get("shipment").get("receiverGeography"), geo), builder.equal(root.join("entries").get("collect").get("geography"), geo)

Comment: @Dmytro Chasovskyi Nope. repository.findAll(Specification.where(shipmentSpec).or(Specification.where(collectSpec))) doesn't return anything too. I updated question.